# Using JarEntry to write sound files is not working as intended

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

```
public static void writeFile(String theFileName, String theFilePath)
{
    try {
        File currentFile = new File("plugins/mcMMO/Resources/"+theFilePath+theFileName);
        //System.out.println(theFileName);
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(plugin.mcmmo);
        JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry("resources/"+theFileName);
        InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(entry);
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int)entry.getSize()];
        is.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(currentFile);
        os.write(buf);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Alright so in my program I have various resources kept within the Jar of the program, when the program runs it has specific files passed to this function that are written to the HDD of the users computer. Everything gets written, but only the images come out 100% correct. The sound files are not so lucky.

Basically, I **CANNOT** get the sounds to write correctly, their file sizes are correct but they only contain a split second of audio instead of their full length audio. Am I missing something here? I seem to have done everything right, but if that was true I wouldn't be posting here.

I tried my best at googling this problem but it has failed me.

**Any guess as to why this doesn't work would be AMAZING!! :)**

Answer (score 0):

As `JarEntry` extends `ZipEntry`, I would recommend not to rely on the `ZipEntry.getSize()` method as it return -1. See the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getSize%28%29).

Moreover, it's in general much more common to take advantage of buffering when reading a stream. In your example, you put everything inside your byte array, so I guess for big files you could end up in an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Here would be the code I would test:

```
public static void writeFile(String theFileName, String theFilePath)
{
    try {
        File currentFile = new File("plugins/mcMMO/Resources/"+theFilePath+theFileName);
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(plugin.mcmmo);
        JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry("resources/"+theFileName);
        InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(entry);
        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
        int nbRead;
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(currentFile));
        while((nbRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            os.write(buf, 0, nbRead);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```